# Inconsistent response between Azure bot and QNAmaker

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I am having inconsistencies with the responses I receive from Azure Bot and Qnamaker Test Chat. Pls see the response from Qnamaker and Azure Bot for the question.

How many FTAs?

Azure Bot:
No good match in FAQ

Qnamaker Test chat:
900 clients

I need to contact someone in Sydney

Azure Bot:
No good match in FAQ

Qnamaker Test chat:
Alex, David, Roland

I tried publishing the knowledgebase multiple times but for some questions, the Azure Bot doesnt give the right answer when Qnamaker Test chat answers it effectively.

My Azure Bot is a C# Question and Answer Bot. Azure Bot answers most of the questions as per the Qnamaker knowledgebase but for some questions like the example above, the bot cannot answer by the Qnamaker does answer them perfectly.

Anyone has any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Does the bot answer any QnAMaker questions correctly?  Or is it always returning "No good match in FAQ"?

Comment: The bot answers 90% of the questions, only for some questions I receive a "No good match in FAQ", whereas the qnamaker test chat was able to answer all the questions.

Comment: This issue I am facing looks similar to the one explained below, but the resolution is not clear,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473908/inconsistent-response-between-azure-qnamaker-web-app-bot-and-cognitive-service

Comment: I think the "matching threshold" on QnAMaker tester chat is very low, maybe even 0. Lower your threshold value on your bot and you will have the same results

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, how do I change the threshold value to zero on my bot.. ?

Comment: Are you getting proper response if you are making API call using PostMan or Curl?